# process A starts B and waits forever when B fails ??? ipc design needed !

Tags: ipc

i have the following Problem: i have two Processes process A which starts process B and have to wait
until process B returns some info, which is needed for further work of process A. the problem is
that Process B may fail and break its work, process A doesnt know about it and keeps waiting!

in this case what is the ideal communication way, and how would you ensure that process A knows if process B
still working or not (without Watchdog timer)?

for the interprocess-communication i considered named pipes, sockets and simply a file on the disk as 
the information process B provides process A with, can be saved in text.

any ideas to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let B create a Mutex on startup and lock it. Then, make A wait for it using WaitForSingleObject api. The Mutex is automatically destroyed when its owner process is terminated, but you can release it sooner if you like to (for instance, B can release the mutex to notify A that it's ready, while it still has some cleaning up to do. That will keep A from waiting unnecessarily long.)

You can specify a timeout too, if you like, so you can give B a maximum time to execute before A will stop waiting.

Comment: Thanx for your answer, but will process A get informed if the Mutex is destroyed too or only if released?

Comment: Process A is always notified, and you can even tell by the return value whether it is actually released by B or 'abandoned' (meaning the process ended while the mutex was still locked). Please check the WaitForSingleObject documentation.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_2918.asp?SK=